# iOS: Receiving keys like cmd-B from a physical keyboard on an iPad app

Tags: ios, api, keyboard

There are apps that can do this. For example, Quick Office can interpret <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> from a physical keyboard to boldface text in a document.

What APIs in the iOS SDK will allow me to get keyboard input such as this? Doesn't look like `UIResponder` has any keyboard-related methods?

Comment: You may need a custom keyboard for this.

Answer (score 0):

You first would need to determine how to track for a boldface.  cmd + b wouldn't work because there is no cmd key on the iOS keyboards.

[image: keyboard image]

One possible solution could be to use the `textFieldTextDidChange` method to grab current value of a text field and perhaps track for BOLD then throw out that substring and modify the styling moving forward to set the font styling.